# How to add activity button in Android widget

Tags: android, android-widget

This is the first time that I need to create an home widget for android.

I need to define buttons in my `widget_layout` to launch some activities so I have created a class `WidgetProvider` that extends `AppWidgetProvider` and shows the Widget in the Home, but I have noticed that there isn't `onCreate`, so I haven't understod how to exactly link the button in my layout xml with a listener that can open the desired activity.

There are many widget on the market that have buttons of this kind.

how should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In widgets you have to use `RemoteViews` instead of `View`, and there is no `findViewById()`, and therefore no `setOnClickListener()`. What you can do however is use `remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(id, pendingIntent)`. Here's a minimal way to open the activity using this:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        Intent appIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        appIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent appPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE, appIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, appPendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but cannot resolve `REQUEST_CODE` what is exactly and how have I to use this?

Comment: REQUEST_CODE could be any integer you want. It's used to identify the pendingIntent. For example when you press the button many times rapidly and send the same PendingIntent multiple times before it has a chance to be carried out, they are identified as the same pending intent since they have the same request code (change the behavior with PendingIntent.FLAGS).

Comment: thanks! if you can please give a look to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397265/appwidgetids-and-best-way-to-define-multiple-size-widget