# appWidgetIds and best way to define multiple size (or resizable) widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to define multiple size widgets I have sees in other questions that a common practice is to define multiple receivers and providers, however in the `onUpdate` method I have noticed that there is an array named `appWidgetIds` eg

```
public void onUpdate(Context c, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
.....
....
  }
}
```

so I'm wondering what is the purpose of this array and if could be used for define multiple size widget without create different providers and receivers.

Note that my different size widget use the same design with the difference that in smaller widgets some elements are missing, for this reason a way to avoid to define multiple providers that do almost the same things is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The array is in case they put multiple instances of the widget, so they can all be updated. Most of the time you call the same update code on all widget id's, but this allows you to pick different actions such as if your app has multiple accounts on it, they can have different widgets.

Sizes are specified with the receivers as described in older apis, while newer ones are capable of resizing.

Comment: could you give me more info about resizing?

Comment: If you take a look here at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#MetaData at the dev website, they show a resize mode option in xml to allow for either vertical or horizontal resizing in the widget info xml file.

Comment: Man, I really need to learn how to format these things from my phone. But that should have the data you need.